# Error when I add a new file using 'sd add' in source depot

Tags: perforce, source-depot

I tried to add a new file using

> sd add myfile.txt

But I get this error saying

> myfile.txt - file(s) not in client view.

Can you please tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: You might find this background material on Perforce workspace views and mappings helpful to understand the concepts here: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4guide/chapter.configuration.html#DB5-54093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer is that you need to edit the client view and/or root ("sd client") so that your local "myfile.txt" is mapped to the depot.

For a more specific answer I'd need to know:

1. The full local path of myfile.txt
2. The full depot path you want to add it to

Comment: I cd to the diretory of the file ("myfile.txt") and then do 'sd add myfile.txt'. The full local path is C:\dev\tools\bin\config\myflie.txt". I don't know the full depot path? I assume it is same directory as my local stucture.

Comment: This is a new file -- where in the depot do you want it to go?  Do you want it to be "//depot/myfile.txt"?  "//depot/config/myfile.txt"?  "//depot/bin/config/myfile.txt"?  "//depot/some/other/dir/myfile.txt"?  "//depot/unrelated/somename.txt"?  Your client view and client root will determine what depot path your local path maps to.